# Excel - categorize an entry from an array of keywords

Tags: excel

So my situation:

I have thousands of entries in a column of business locations. I have created a table of of categories with associated keywords. The idea is that if a location has one of these keywords in its name, it will have a certain category as a result.

So in B1 I have a category of "Hotels" and in C1, "Inn", D1, "hotel", E1, "lodge", etc.
And in C2, I have another category name called "Retail" with keywords going across to the right such as "Mall" in D2, "Shopping" in E2, etc. There are 20 such categories in a table i a separate tab that the locations tab will reference for the categorization.

If the entry has any of these words, I want to a new column next to it called "Category" to return "Hotel" in the same row. It is easy to do this for just the hotel category since that is just a boolean return.

But I have 20 categories like this and do not want to manually write the find statements for all of them because I want to search for all of the keywords and return the matching category name. Is there a succinct way of doing this?

One idea I had is to delimit each location string by spaces and splice the words into an array, then say if any of theme match the horizontal arrays next to the category names in the reference table, find the row of the match (since all the category names are in the same column) and complete the cell reference with an indirect. I am not sure how to write such a statement and if that is the optimal way to address this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If possible, I'd like to find a solution in plain Excel...no experience in VBA

Comment: Actually, an array formula would work after all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for the problem as specified, assuming A2 and on down have values.  I used LOWER to fix them all to lowercase, remove that if not needed.  It is an array formula, so ctrl+shift+enter.

```
=MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND(C$1:E$2,LOWER($A3)),0)>0,1,0)*ROW(C$1:E$2))
```

Comment: What about the other categories? I have 20 categories starting with B1 down to B20 and each has associated keywords to the right. I want to be able to search for all the keywords and return the associated category from column B next to each location entry in a separate tab.

Comment: Change the formula for your needs.  I thought you had them across the top; across B1-B20 is fine also, just change B$1:D$1 to $B$1:$B$20.

Comment: Modifed to include ROW() function to generate the array of rows.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am not explaining it well. I have category names in B1:B20 but then keywords going across C1:X20 for each of the categories. Not all of the cells are filled in with a keyword because some categories have more words than others. This is the reference tab. In the locations tab, I have locations going down in column C and want to put the category name from column B in the reference tab in column B of the locations tab. The category inserted should be based on which keyword was found in the location entry and insert the associated category. I tried this solution but did not work.

Comment: That roughly matches what I have (cat. names in B, elements in C and beyond).  What's not working?

Comment: Thank you, I just had to remove the LOWER b/c it was breaking the finds. Works great